# How do I use mongoose's aggregate to assign each item a score based on an equation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make a sorting algorithm that will find the most trendy questions,
here is the equation I use:

```
Rating = (AV * (1 / 50)) + (AL * 3) - (AD * 6)
```

Rating is the thing I want to sort by, the ones with the highest rating would be most trendy,

AV is the average views, calculated by Views/days ago

AL is average likes, calculated by Likes/days ago

AD is average dislikes, calculated by Dislikes/days ago

here is the question scheme which the documents we are sorting:

```
const Question = mongoose.model(
  "Question",
  new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    text: { type: String },
    authorUsername: { type: String, required: true },
    dateCreated: {},
    answers: { type: Array, required: true },
    likes: { type: Array, required: true },
    dislikes: { type: Array, required: true },
    tag: { type: String, required: true },
    views: {type: Array, required:true},
  })
);
```

and here is an example of a question

```
document:_id:620935985f6865b4e85c333d,
title:"How do i make a lemon?",
text:"yeet",
authorUsername:"SweetWhite",
dateCreated:2022-02-13T16:45:12.598+00:00,
answers: Array,
likes:
0:1,
1:"SweetWhite",
dislikes: Array,
0:0,
tag:
"Social",
views:Array,
0:1,
1:"SweetWhite",
__v:0
```

it is important to note I store the length of the views, likes, dislikes, arrays in the first item which is a number, so if you use $size it would be one too big.

can anybody use Question.aggregate with the equation above and the document to filter out the 15 most trendy questions(highest rating)?

Thanks!
EDIT:
here is my following work I did:

```
router.get('/questions/hot', async (req,res,next) => {
  try{
    const results = await Question.aggregate([
        /*{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]},
        {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]},
        {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$views",[0]]}, 0]}*/
      {$project: {rating: {$add:[
        {$divide: 
          [
            {$divide: [{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$views",[0]]}, 0]},  1]},
            50
          ]},
        {$subtract: 
          [
            {$multiply: [{$divide: [{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]},  1]}, 3]},
            {$multiply: [{$divide: [{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]},  1]}, 6]}
          ]
        }
        ]}
      }},
      {$sort: {rating:-1}},
      {$limit: 15}
    ]).exec();
    console.log(results)
    const questions = await Promise.all(results.map(({_id}) => Question.findOne({_id}).exec()));
    res.render('content', { whichOne: 5, user: req.user, questions:questions});
  }
  catch(err){
    next(err);
  }
});
```

it is pretty close, there is already a score and it is functionaing, the only problem it is that the average like/days dislike/days views/days is not right, since I cant find a way to check how many days ago were it created using the date I have. so for now it is divided by 1 instead of days ago. Would appreciate if someone tells me how to do it

Comment: Please add a valid JSON document.

Comment: Please also provide your latest attempt so community here can based on your current work to offer help that fit your needs more.

Comment: just did it ray, I already got everything done except the dates thng to find the average views/day likes/day dislikes/day

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just managed to solve this! In case this helps someone one day:

```
router.get('/questions/hot', async (req,res,next) => {
  try{
    let now = new Date();
    const results = await Question.aggregate([
        /*{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]},
        {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]},
        {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$views",[0]]}, 0]}*/
      {$project: {rating: {$add:[
        {$divide: 
          [
            {$divide: [{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$views",[0]]}, 0]},  {$subtract:[now, '$dateCreated']}]},
            50
          ]},
        {$subtract: 
          [
            {$multiply: [{$divide: [{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]}, {$subtract:[now, '$dateCreated']}]}, 3]},
            {$multiply: [{$divide: [{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]},  {$subtract:[now, '$dateCreated']}]}, 6]}
          ]
        }
        ]}
      }},
      {$sort: {rating:-1}},
      {$limit: 15}
    ]).exec();
    console.log(results)
    const questions = await Promise.all(results.map(({_id}) => Question.findOne({_id}).exec()));
    res.render('content', { whichOne: 5, user: req.user, questions:questions});
  }
  catch(err){
    next(err);
  }
});
```